# REGEXP Help to remove Control Characters || leading numerical characters || = sign

Tags: regex, notepad++

As per above title, I'm trying to remove certain characters from a FIX file to be replaced with a `~`.

The string resembles the below which I want to remove *sequences* of SOH control characters, the numerical characters and the equals sign and to replace this all with a `~`:

[image: screenshot]

What regular expression should I use in order to achieve that?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. As much as I appreciate the little introduction you should know that in SO you should ask your question only. Check that out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, could you please paste your code/text instead of linking an image, I'm behind proxy and don't have access to imgur.

Comment: Could you please show what you tried to understand how to help you? Your question does not really explain what problem you have.

Comment: Are you working in Notepad++? Try `\x01`

Comment: Got it guys, I'm using the following..  \x01+\d+=

Answer (score 1):

> remove sequences of SOH control characters, the numerical characters and the equals sign and to replace this all with a `~`

So, you may use `\x01\d+=` regex and replace with a `~`.

**Pattern details**

- `\x01` - a SOH char (dec. code 01)
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `=` - an equals sign.

This

[image]

turns into

[image]

Settings:

[image]